# Displaying output from different function in one innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to display two outputs in different functions into single innerHTML when the button clicked. However, I want it without using a global variable to store the output. I have tried using array for storing the string output, however, the error is whether the output is not displayed correctly or it will keep storing the string output when I used push() to store output inside the array

**The HTML:**

```
<div>
  <button type="button" id="display">display</button>
  <button type="button" id="stats">stats </button>
  <p id="msg"></p>
</div>
```

**The Script:**

```
//declare global array
var array = [1,2,3];

function list(){
  var output ="";
  var i;
  for (i =0; i < array.length; i++){
    output = output + " " + array[i];
  }
  //this output will be displayed when the first button is clicked
  output = "List of all values in the array: <br>" + output + "<br>"; 
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = output;
}

function stats(){
  var output = "";
  var sum = 0;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  output = output + "The number of values in the array: " + array.length + "<br>The total of all values in the array: " + sum;

  //here I want to display the output of list() function + stats() 
  //when the second button is clicked
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = output;
}

function init() {
  var btnList = document.getElementById("display");
  var btnStats = document.getElementById("stats");
  btnList.onclick = list;
  btnStats.onclick = stats;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple just call `list()` inside `stats()` and then append the innerHTML.

The updated Script

```js
var array = [1,2,3];

function list(){
  var output ="";
  var i;
  for (i =0; i < array.length; i++){
    output = output + " " + array[i];
  }
  //this output will be displayed when the first button is clicked
  output = "List of all values in the array: <br>" + output + "<br>"; 
  debugger;
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = output;
}

function stats(){
  var output = "";
  var sum = 0;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  output = output + "The number of values in the array: " + array.length + "<br>The total of all values in the array: " + sum;

  //here I want to display the output of list() function + stats() 
  //when the second button is clicked
  list();
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML += output;
}

function init() {
  var btnList = document.getElementById("display");
  var btnStats = document.getElementById("stats");
  btnList.onclick = list;
  btnStats.onclick = stats;
}

init();
```